# PHP Not getting json using curl

Tags: php

The main function is that one but I don't get any values, it works fine in a 000webhost domain but with a VPS I don't recieve any values.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPVMV.png)
I have already installed php-curl and php-json, Am I missing some dependency?

**Php Code**

```
<?php 
//Building A Simple Bittrex Bot
$apikey='2923c158d5754c29a088c4adea5c6f34';
$apisecret='3f29b39ab1be46afb0834fe56c8e4fea';
function bittrexbalance($apikey, $apisecret){
    $nonce=time();
    $uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance?apikey='.$apikey.'&currency=BTC&nonce='.$nonce;
    $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($execResult, true);
    $balance = $obj["result"]["Available"];
    return $balance;
}
?>
```

Here is the link to code on the [github](https://github.com/coinables/bittrex/blob/master/index.php).

Comment: Post your code here instead of a image

Comment: Hope this isn't your valid API credentials...

Comment: Those are the display API credentials..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is obviously here:

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

The documentation of [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) clearly [states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure. However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is [set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), it will return the result on success, `FALSE` on failure.

Add a call to [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) passing `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to let [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) know you want it to return and not to display the body of the HTTP response.

```
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specified, the function that is not working is bittrexbalance..